# Should I continue working on project after graduating?

Tags: research-undergraduate

Background: I finished a masters level degree 7 months ago, and got very positive feedback from my supervisors and markers on the research work I did. The research included developing a novel technique, my supervisor said it was of publishable standard and agreed to help me work on submitting it for publication after graduating. Since there was no funding available to take me on as a research assistant, I agreed to do this work unpaid while working an unrelated part time job.

My current situation: I've moved to a new place and have been working on the project remotely. It turns out that to publish the technique, more work than I originally thought is necessary to generate sufficiently convincing results. I think I was somewhat unrealistic in how much time I could dedicate to this unpaid work while working part time and having a life. I also feel that there is nobody in the group willing to push the work forward other than myself, as it's somewhat tangential to their current research topics. I am still motivated by the chance to publish the work, but less so than when I was directly involved with the group.

My question: should I continue pushing ahead slowly with this work, or cut my losses and call it quits? I know there is no one-size-fits-all answer, but maybe somebody can share similar experiences in continuing with a project while no longer having a formal role with a research group. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Is your aim a career in academia? In that case a publication is quite certainly worthwhile.

Comment: What is your current job?

Answer (score 2):

Under these circumstances your only responsibility is to yourself.

If you still find the work interesting for its own sake, keep at it - but only at a pace that allows you to do your day job and have a life.

If that's not possible, just move on.